# iOS: Multi-layers of modally presented navigation controller slows down VC presentation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a navigation controller say navA, which can present (ie modally) another navigation controller navB, and navB can also present another navigation controller navC, I've observed that randomly there can be a delay when navB presents navC, I tried to log before navB presents navC and also in the completion block:

```
// inside a VC which is on navB's stack:

NSLog(@"started");
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navC animated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"completed");
}];
```

Has anyone seen this kind of issue? Or is there any other issue I've missed?

Update:

I put some log in different VC life cycle methods:

> 2014-12-11 10:16:41.631 ####### [78210:7119850] DID INIT
>
> 2014-12-11 10:16:41.631 ####### [78210:7119850] DID FINISH INIT
>
> 2014-12-11 10:17:00.007 ####### [78210:7119850] DID LOAD
>
> 2014-12-11 10:17:00.010 ####### [78210:7119850] WILL APPEAR
>
> 2014-12-11 10:17:00.517 ####### [78210:7119850] DID APPEAR

So after `viewDidLoad`, it took nearly 19 seconds to call `viewWillAppear`, I guess it's doing some internal view hierarchy work before loading/presenting the view?

Update 2:

This seems to be a common issue on iOS 8+, a quick fix is to put the presentVC... code inside the dispatch_async block on main queue.

Comment: 1. viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear method have a lot of code that hang your UI part.
2. code run on main Thread or not.

Comment: @SumitGarg 1. Yes I also think so 2. It is on main thread. But I'm not presenting three nav controller one after another, in the instance, there are already two nav controllers presented one on top of the other, and I'm presenting a third one on top of the second one.